# What is a pending test in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

What is the use of a pending test in RSpec?

ex:

```
xit "it is named Ash" do
```

or

```
it "it is named Ash"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

The idea is to disable an example temporarily. Pending examples are not executed and are marked as pending.

One use case for this is if you want to run an entire spec except one or two examples. Instead of commenting them out, you can mark them as pending. Another reason is to write specs for something you know has to get implemented, but currently isn't.

In the execution report you will see

> x examples, y failures, z pending

---

To mark an example as pending, you can either put an `x` in front of the `it`, as you have found out, or put in the place that you want to be pending:

```
pending 'some reason'
```

If you do the latter, the code in that example will be executed, but the example will count as pending instead of a success or failure.

Examples that don't have a body (`do` - `end` block) are also considered pending.

Comment: "the code in that example will be executed up until the point of the invocation of #pending". Not my experience if I put a pending statement within a do block - the code after it executes. rspec 3.8. It just doesn't mark it as a a failure, and notes: "Pending: (Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status)" above the pending examples.

Comment: This is simply not true... Tests marked as `pending` in their input will still execute.

Comment: @JeffWidman What do you mean by "in their input"?

Comment: Tests can be marked as "pending" by the user (ie, input) vs marked as pending by `rspec` (ie, output)... see: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/3014

Answer (score 1):

As a test input, `pending()` refers to tests that run, but are expected to fail. In fact a `pending()` test that suddenly passes will fail the test run. The ideal use case is if you run tests against external APIs that suddenly stop working for a day or two, you can mark as pending to unblock CI but still notify you when you can re-enable them.

This is in contrast to `skip()` which causes the test to be entirely skipped without running. For example if you've got a particular test that passes, but
takes a long time to run, you may want to only run locally when working on that area of code, but mark as `skip()` so that it's ommitted from CI.

Confusingly, both "skipped" and "pending" tests are printed with a `pending` output:

```
# test marked as skipped

1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

In general, the concept of pending as a test that is still run is relatively uncommon in other language testing ecosystems. Between that and the overloading of the term "pending" for the test outcome, it's no wonder people get confused and think that `pending()` and `skipped()` are the same!